# Coding a simple trading strategy on Python

Tags: python, pandas, finance, trading

Apologies in advance for the long post (please advice if these long posts are poor form). :(

Attempting to code a simple trading strategy to learn how to calculate expected returns and financial trading methods.

I have here loaded S&P 500 data from Yahoo Finance using `yfinance`. I then loaded the data, and I wanted the user to be able to input how far back the data goes.

Here already begins my problem. My dataframe is loaded such that the "close_price" list has the dates as an index column (can be seen also in the attached image). Not my biggest concern as I'm able to call all the dates and close_prices for the stock I've selected.

From here, I'm trying to calculate the expected returns based on two strategies:

1. Buy $x on the first date. Buy $x every month thereafter. Calculate the portfolio value (or returns on each investment/total returns) on a specified date.
2. Buy $x on the first date. Buy $x again if the price drops by 10%. Sell 0.5*$x if the price increases by 10%. Buy $x if 30 days have surpassed and no buy/sell order has been made.

[Picture of my data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkdUy.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as web

# Load stock data
stock_ticker = '^GSPC'
df = yf.download(stock_ticker)

# Allows user to input number of days to trackback prior to today (excluding weekends) for analysis
timescale = int(input("Enter No. of days prior to today (excluding weekends):")) 

# List arrays for close price and dates
close_price = df["Adj Close"][-timescale:]
dates = df.index.tolist()[-timescale:]

# Returns
daily_returns = close_price.pct_change(fill_method='pad')
monthly_returns = close_price.resample('M').ffill().pct_change(fill_method='pad')
```

Things I've tried:

-- Writing a for loop that calculates the multiplies my monthly stock return (monthly return values are of the order 0.01 and stock prices of the order $4000) against my investments per month. So $1000 investment, one month later return is 0.04, so returns are 40, value of portfolio = $1040

-- Write a while loop that is True while the stock prices from the initial value are greater than 0.90% of it. If not True: put $1000 into the stock. If the stock goes up 10% (or if the price from the last buy/sell order is < 1.1x), then sell 50%.

I've tried many ways to logic this in code, but to no avail. Would love your help guys!

Thanks!

Comment: Try breaking down your problem into more manageable chunks, e.g.: 1. tracking what assets/qty are held, 2. what is the value of current assets held, and 3. `should security X be a buy/sell today`. Once you can accurately buy/sell [manually] and calculate portfolio value over time, move on to #3.

Answer (score 0):

There are some modules such as Zipline that can help simulate these trading strategies I think. It might be less time consuming to use that and it incorporates things like slippage and trading fees as well.

However if you want to build your own code from scratch I’d suggest breaking it down into a few smaller steps.

Firstly a section of code that finds trade signals buy/sell, based on your previously stated criteria.

Then another section of code that takes the trading signals and finds trades with entry/exit dates.

When you have a list of trades with entry/exit dates you can create a section of code that turns the list of trades into a portfolio database. The database shows the value of your portfolio over time and how your trades effect that value.